# AngularJs best way to repeat html code with the ability to hide it

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

new to AngularJs. In my html, I have two table rows that are repeated and populated over and over again. I need the second row to appear/disappear if I click a button on the first row. Here is some pseudo-ish, incomplete angular in what I'm aiming for

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in collection" id="firstTr">
  <td>
    <button type="button" ng-click="toggleTheSecondTr">
        toggle visibility for second tr
    </button>
  <td>
  <td>
    {{item.value}}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-Hide="the above button got clicked" id="secondTr" ng-repeat-end>
  <td>
     something goes here, there can be many td's
  </td>
  <td>
    {{item.someOtherValue}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

This block of code is going to be repeated over and over again. But, I need to bind the button in a way that when the button is clicked, the second row is hidden, or if clicked again, it is shown again, almost like a toggle switch. I'm not sure how to do this. I could keep track of it with variables in the typescript code behind (we used typescript, not js) but I have no gaurantee on how many times these two rows will be repeated and therefore no idea how many variables to keep track of. Suggestions on how to solve my issue?

edit: I essentially want the functionality very similar to the table in this page for example, but my number of rows is variable, it can be one or many https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

Comment: Notice the small case `ng-hide` instead of `ng-Hide`, the `toggleTheSecondTr` needs to be a function call by using `toggleTheSecondTr()` and you need the function to exist in $scope in your controller. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there an id or unique value for each `item` in `collection`? If so, you could use a map to keep track of what gets shown/hidden.

Comment: Yes, the items in the collection are unique, they are taken from a json with ~30-40 different properties

Comment: A table like the top of this page is essentially what I am trying to accomplish, where clicking the + button unhides table rows to reveal more information https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/.

Comment: But in my case the number of rows can be anywhere from 1 to 50 to 500, it's dynamically populated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution mate:
Use a boolean variable in each object of the collection to show or hide the second `<tr>` in its respective section:

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.collection = [];
    $scope.collection.push({value:'Test', someOtherValue:'UAT', hideSecondRow: false});
    $scope.collection.push({value:'Dev', someOtherValue:'Development', hideSecondRow: true});
    $scope.collection.push({value:'Prod', someOtherValue:'PreProd', hideSecondRow: false});
    $scope.toggleTheSecondTr = function(index){
      $scope.collection[index].hideSecondRow = !$scope.collection[index].hideSecondRow;
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="item in collection" id="firstTr">
        <td>
          <button type="button" ng-click="toggleTheSecondTr($index)">
              toggle visibility for second tr
          </button>
        <td>
        <td>
          {{item.value}}
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-hide="item.hideSecondRow" id="secondTr" ng-repeat-end>
        <td>
           something goes here, there can be many td's
        </td>
        <td>
          {{item.someOtherValue}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Yatin, I appreciate the answer. I tested that code, but the issue is for collections greater than one, each button hides every second tr, as opposed to the one just below the button. I'd like the button to just toggle only the tr directly below it. Any suggestions on how to alter the controller or html code to acheive this functionality for sizes greater than one?

Comment: @pdaniels0013 here you go mate; I have updated the solution to contain a boolean value inside each object which can be modified to show/hide the second row in its respective section. Let me know if this one works for you.